# Calling ASM function in C++

Tags: c++, assembly

Trying to call ASM function in C++.. regular function

you may ask what type of function this is.. __cdecl, __stdcall, or __thiscall

I think i'm missing something like

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

although i don't think i need this, someone once told me but I forgot so I am stuck at same problem. I usually would attach debugger and fix this.. but I cannot in my case the program doesn't allow debuggers.

I have this function, it is a **__thiscall** function

```
00458BDE     90             NOP
00458BDF     90             NOP
00458BE0  /$ 8B5424 04      MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4]
00458BE4  |. 8B09           MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
00458BE6  |. E8 3589FCFF    CALL Continuu.00421520
00458BEB  \. C2 0400        RETN 4
00458BEE     90             NOP
00458BEF     90             NOP
```

This is what I tried, didn't work

```
int testFuncAddr = 0x00421520; 
__declspec(naked) void Test(int buffer, int key)
{
    __asm{
        push edx
        push ecx
        mov edx, key
        mov ecx, buffer
        call [testFuncAddr]
        ret
    }
}
```

Don't really know what to do that about sums it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

firstly, your function is `__fastcall` (as EDX is used), so this means you can typedef it in C:

```
typedef void (__fastcall * function_t)(int buffer, int key);
function_t pfTheFunc = (function_t)0x00421520;
```

you should then notice that the `push edx` and `push ecx` are unneeded (they are also volatile registers and thus don't need to be preserved across calls, except if you are sticking call into code where they didn't used to be). and if they where to preserve, they needed a matching set of `pop`s

```
__declspec(naked) void Test(int buffer, int key)
{
    __asm{
        push edx
        push ecx
        mov edx, key
        mov ecx, buffer
        call [testFuncAddr]
        pop ecx
        pop edx
        ret
    }
}
```

also:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

that just creates a stackframe, it has no real being on the actual function(unless you know the binary was compiled without frame pointers, in which case it shows use of inline assembly in a non-naked function)

Comment: Thanks sorry I forget things often.. well atleast now i'll keep this on my SO account. Also `typedef function` **works properly**.. but the assembly equivalent doesn't work, meh I don't even want it anymore.. I think now that `ret` doesn't belong there either. So just `mov edx, key`
        `mov ecx, buffer`
        `call [testFuncAddr]` should work?  Well if i recall now I think it really needed `pushad` `popad` wrapping it for it to work?

Comment: @SSpoke: you only need `mov edx, key`;`mov ecx, buffer`;`call [testFuncAddr]`;`retn` (though you can just `JMP` instead of `CALL` and drop away the `RETN`). that second snippet was just to demonstrate correct register preserving (should work though)